# What is NUMA node limit in modern Windows OS

Tags: windows, numa

What is the highest number of NUMA nodes in Windows 10 / Server 2012? In Windows 7, it was documented that OS supports only up to 4 NUMA nodes[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653313(v=vs.85).aspx) but with modern systems supporting 320 logical processors this clearly cannot be the case anymore.

Answer (score 1):

HP Sold an Itanium-based 64-socket/NUMA-node Integrity server that ran Windows Server 2003 for Itanium and Server 2008R2 supports 64 x64 sockets/NUMA nodes, I can't find any details for Server 2012R2 but I'd imagine it supports the same limits or more. No idea about client OSs.